# how do i change the fonts in the BIDS package designer?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ssis, bids

i went to: menu > tools >options > fonts and colors > business intelligence designers...but nothing happened when i changed the font size.  i'm using visual studio 2008

what am i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the relevant component from the "Show setting for:" drop down, when you apply your font and colors prferences.

For example, selecting "Business Intelligence Designers" will change the fonts for the Control Flow and Data Flow tab etc.